# How do i validate it so that the first 3 digits range 100-300(inclusive) and the second 3 digits range 001-999(inclusive) in the following

Tags: java, decimal

```
private boolean validateSno(double inSno) {
  //sno is the serial number


  int firstThree=(int)inSno;
  double secondThree=(inSno-firstThree)*1000;
  boolean same=false;
  double checkDigit=inSno*1000-(int)inSno;

  if(checkDigit>0.0)
  {
  same=false;
  }
  else 
  {
      if(firstThree>=100&&firstThree<=300)
      {
      if(secondThree>=001&&secondThree<=999)
      {
          same=true;
      }

      }
  }
  return same;
}
```

I need the result to be in form XXX.YYY but as it is a real number I am stuck on how to split the first 3 numbers and the second 3 numbers.
Each has its own validation required

is there an easy way using mod/div or?

Comment: Basically the question just asks to validate the serial number (double) in the form XXX.YYY where the first 3 numbers (XXX) need to be between 100 and 300 (inclusive) and the second 3 numbers (YYY) need to be between 001 and 999(inclusive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example number 456.234

```
double number = 456.234;
double firstThree = (int)number; \\ output 456
double lastThree = (number * 1000 % 1000); \\ output 234
```

Comment: only problem is that it is a real number. eg. 456.234

Comment: Please add this fact to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider to use a string and a stringtokenizer class.

It's a tricky way but not so bad.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class TestAnyParser {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        validateSno(456.234);
    }

    private static boolean validateSno(double inSno) {
        boolean isReal = false;

        String sInSno = String.valueOf(inSno);

        StringTokenizer stTok = new StringTokenizer(sInSno, ".");

        isReal = stTok.countTokens() == 2;


        if(isReal)
        {

            int realpart = Integer.parseInt(stTok.nextToken());
            int imgpart =  Integer.parseInt(stTok.nextToken());

            System.out.println(realpart + ": " + imgpart);
        }
        else
        {
            //do something part.
        }


        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following uses string validation with a regular expression to check that numbers are the right length and in the right range

```
private boolean validateSno(double inSno) {
    String serial = String.valueOf(inSno);
    return serial.matches("[1-3]\\d{2}\\.[1-9][\\d]{2}\\d*");
}
```

Note the extra `\\d*"` at the end, this is to also approve a value like 123.45600000001